# Is it possible to alter #include filenames using #define?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm working with some old C++ code that, apparently, pre-dates the standardization and move from `iostream.h` to `iostream`, and similarly for other includes. Consequently, my relatively modern version of g++ fails when trying to `#include <iostream.h>`, etc.

I'm curious if it's possible to use the preprocessor to change instances of `iostream.h` to just `iostream`, via the command line. I've tried appending `-Diostream.h=iostream` to g++, but that doesn't seem to alter the include statements.

I'm guessing it's not possible for the preprocessor to modify include statements?

Comment: Won't a simple script in your favorite scripting language, do better?

Comment: Why not simply build the code, get lots of errors, fix those errors, and so on? Sure the code can no longer be built by the old pre-standard compilers, but at least it will be possible to continue using modern compilers now and in the future.

Comment: Just do a global search and replace. You'll need to do some other fixups also, such as adding `using namespace std;` or appropriate qualifications. Some of this can be automated, some of it can't, really.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Since when is adding `using namespace std;` a fixup?

Comment: @DeiDei: Is that question about the terminology or is it a kind of silly associative thing, that you think that directive is no-no-foul?

Comment: These comments are all valid, but I'm still curious if it's possible to using defines to modify include statements or not. I've already compiled the code after doing a global search and replace, and adding the proper `using` statements where needed. `-fpermissive` was required as well since apparently scoping of variables in `for` definitions changed, which I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @sackoverfowl: You can use macros to generate header names for `#include`, and that's always been so. However, it's a hassle. A main problem is that different compilers generally have different non-conforming ways to do preprocessing, so e.g. how to concatenate stuff becomes a nightmare. Or it was a nightmare, some years back. It's not a good idea to go that route, unless one desires much pain & frustration.

Answer (score 8):

There are three forms of the `#include` statement.

```
# include "h-char-sequence" new-line

# include <h-char-sequence> new-line

# include pp-tokens new-line
```

where `pp-tokens` must expand to one of the first two forms.

You could use:

```
#include IOSTREAM
```

and compile with `-DIOSTREAM="<iostream>"` or `-DIOSTREAM="<iostream.h>"` depending on the version of compiler you are working with.

However, you can't use

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

and compile with `-Diostream.h=iostream`.

There are couple of problems with that.

1. `iostream.h` is not a valid preprocessor macro.
2. The form of the `#include` statement is not appropriate for macro expansion.

If you are ready to migrate your code base to use the new C++ headers, you will be better off using your favorite scripting method to change all the old style C++ headers to new C++ headers.